# How to calculate and save a derived ActiveRecord value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a data object which is composed_of three child instances of the same object.  I need to calculate a value from that object and save it in the database.  (It is later pulled form the db by another application.)

I've mocked out my class structure below, basically I want a method that will add together the Child values data_one and data_two, and store it into a third variable, total.  Which I guess will be total_first, total_second and total_third in the db Parent table.   Should I declare total as a Child attribute and use a callback to set it?  Any help will be much appreciated - thank you!  And apologies if this is a really obvious question...

```
class Child

  attr_reader :data_one, :data_two

  def initialize(data_one, data_two)
    @data_one, @data_two, 
  end

  def ==(other_child)
    data_one           == other_child.data_one           && 
    data_two           == other_child.data_two             
  end

  def Sdq.from_params(hash)
    Sdq.new(
      get_value(hash, :data_one),
      get_value(hash, :data_two),
    )
  end

  protected
    def Sdq.get_value(hash, key)
      hash.has_key?(key) ? hash[key] : hash[key.to_s]
    end
end 


class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

  composed_of :first_child, :class_name => "Child", :mapping => [
    ["data_one_first","data_one"],
    ["data_two_first","data_two"]
  ]

  composed_of :second_child, :class_name => "Child", :mapping => [
    ["data_one_second","data_one"],
    ["data_two_second","data_two"]
  ]

  composed_of :third_child, :class_name => "Child", :mapping => [
    ["data_one_third","data_one"],
    ["data_two_third","data_two"]
  ]

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine why a parent will always have exactly two children, why not a many_to_x relation? depending if you need many to many. Hopefully not seeing the example.

You must have your reasons.

I would use call backs like you described. Maybe `before_validations` and have some validation on it. Note, that returning a non-true value in a callback can result in the record *not* saving.

E.G If the condition is false, the method returns nil and can halt the save callback chain.

```
def before_save
   if something_sometimes_is_false
       #do normal code
   end # could not run, which would return nil and break things
end
```

consider returning self at the end.

```
def before_save
    if something_sometimes_is_false
        # do normal code
    end
    self # should always be a true value in an instance of a class. will not break call backs
end
```

Comment: Thanks, the relationship is set up like that to enrich the model - the fields are stored in the Parent table, but named Child objects can be used though the app to enable additional methods to be called.  It does seem quite cumbersome, but I'm not sure if there is another way to do it?  In your example, should I set the value on the Child object?  Will it automatically update the Parent table?? Many thanks!

Comment: @lainie it will update the parent table when you call save on an instance of a Parent. Provided your mappings are correct and the like. If they aren't you will get an exception letting you know whats up.